# Storing a model object with Lists in Room Database

Tags: java, android, android-room

Having a look at the various online resources, on this topic, I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a model object that looks like this: `HomeResponse`

```
@Entity(tableName = "HomeData")
public class HomeResponse {

  @PrimaryKey
  public  int counts;

  public List<Trade> mTrades;
}
```

I have have my `Trade`s object that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Trade {
  public int tradeId;
  public String title;
}
```

The first thing I looked at, was a [@TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter.html)
However this seems to work only for POJO's that only contain primitive fields.

It seems then, what I am looking for would be a [@ForeignKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html)

This still doesn't feel right. As my `Trades` object won't only ever be in a `HomeResponse` object. I may have it in other POLOs that relate to different Tades.

What would be the ideal way to have `HomeResponse` also store the `Trades` object in the DB as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a model object that looks like this: HomeResponse

That is not a suitable Room `@Entity`. Remove the `public List<Trade> mTrades` field.

> It seems then, what I am looking for would be a @ForeignKey

Correct, on `Trade`, pointing back to `HomeResponse`.

> This still doesn't feel right. As my Trades object won't only ever be in a HomeResponse object.  I may have it in other POLOs that relate to different Tades.

I am uncertain what a POLO is. Regardless, entities serve as the model for database tables. Put Room aside for a few minutes and design your table structure. Then, create entity classes that mirror the structure of the tables.

> What would be the ideal way to have HomeResponse also store the Trades object in the DB as well?

It doesn't. Your DAO saves `HomeResponse` objects and `Trade` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response. POLO is a typo, I meant, POJO. What if the Trade object, can belong to many other objects. Other than HomeResponse. Do I then need to have Many ForeginKeys in the Trade object?  - I am having a little luck with TypeConverts, busy experimenting with them.

Comment: @Tander: "Thanks for the response. POLO is a typo, I meant, POJO" -- ah, OK. "Do I then need to have Many ForeginKeys in the Trade object?" -- I have no idea. Again, **design your database structure**. If you did not have Room, and you were implementing this in a plain SQL database, what would your tables look like? For example, if a `Trade` can have many parents (not parent types, but actual parents), you have an M:N relation, which requires a join table (and some sort of corresponding join entity in Room).

Comment: I think if I were to use raw SQL, each trade array would have its own table. As they would be related to different parents, and no two trade tables, would contain the same data, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Tander: OK. That will require two entities, one per table. However, inheritance works, and so you can create a common class that handles all of the common fields, then have two entity classes that inherit from it and introduce anything unique, such as the foreign key specifics. [This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.1/Trips/RoomRelations) shows inheritance like this, as I have an abstract `Plan` which is extended by `Trip`, `Flight`, and `Lodging` entities.

Comment: Thanks for that!  - How does HomeResponse 1. Reference the correct table, and 2. How do I store HomeResponse in the DB (Using the DAO) and the trades array it would have?

Comment: @Tander: `HomeResponse` has nothing to do with trades in Room. Room does not model relationships, only foreign keys. You can use `@Relation` to have a DAO return a `HomeResponse`-ish object that happens to have a `List<Trade>`, but `HomeResponse` itself cannot have a `List<Trade>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150823/discussion-between-tander-and-commonsware).

Comment: Thanks, I have used @ForeginKeys. However I now get the following error, when I try save a List of Trades, to the DB, using homeResponseDao - SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)

Comment: @Tander: Presumably, the trade does not have the proper value for its foreign key. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing your current code and the full stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided not to use ForeignKey or TypeConverter - as you said HomeResponse has no relation to trades, so I am storing the trades separately, and using the homeResponseDao to access them. Thanks for the help!